# Axon complaining on com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Failed calling method

Tags: java, spring, axon

I'm trying to use mysql with JPA for axon event store and I am getting this issue,It was working for me with InMemoryEventStorageEngine.

I have tried it with axon server and InMemoryEventStorageEngine, its working.

Any help is really appreciated thanks

com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Failed calling method
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Failed calling method
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : Failed calling method

### method              : java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject()

```
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.SerializationMembers.callWriteObject(SerializationMembers.java:158)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter.doMarshal(SerializableConverter.java:257)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:274)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:213)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:144)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:274)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:213)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:144)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:274)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:213)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:144)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1319)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1308)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1281)
at org.axonframework.serialization.xml.XStreamSerializer.doSerialize(XStreamSerializer.java:86)
at org.axonframework.serialization.AbstractXStreamSerializer.serialize(AbstractXStreamSerializer.java:98)
at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.AbstractSagaEntry.<init>(AbstractSagaEntry.java:58)
at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.SagaEntry.<init>(SagaEntry.java:41)
at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore.createSagaEntry(JpaSagaStore.java:330)
at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore.insertSaga(JpaSagaStore.java:298)
at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.storeSaga(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:217)
at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.lambda$doCreateInstance$3(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:139)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.MessageProcessingContext.notifyHandlers(MessageProcessingContext.java:71)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.lambda$notifyHandlers$2(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:155)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:899)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.notifyHandlers(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:155)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.changePhase(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:222)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commitAsRoot(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:83)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commit(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:71)
at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:111)
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.processInUnitOfWork(AbstractEventProcessor.java:136)
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:259)
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:181)
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:661)
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:771)
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$CountingRunnable.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The fact the `InMemoryEventStorageEngine` works, is because that will not de-/serialize anything. Thus, the `XStreamSerializer` Axon Framework defaults to wouldn't be used in that scenario.
To get to the point though, place share the exact object which XStream is trying to serialize. It's likely something to do with how you've drafted up the given Event which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Steven mentioned serialization works only when you try to store the events in DB,and you can easily configure your event serialization in your configuration application properties,
I was able to solve it using this configurations

```
axon.serializer.general = jackson
axon.serializer.events = jackson
axon.serializer.messages =Jackson
```

Answer (score 0):

@dawit Do you get the solution or work around to solve it