# Why does 'ConversionException' occur in 'TrackingEventProcessor' of Axon framework?

Tags: spring-boot, axon, saga

- with Axon 4.5
- with Spring Boot 2.5.2
- with Spring JPA

I wrote Saga management as below

```kotlin
@Saga
class OrderSagaManagement {
   @Autowired
   private lateinit var eventGateway: EventGateway

   @StartSaga
   @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "orderId")
   fun handle(orderCreatedEvent: OrderCreatedEvent) {
      val paymentId = Random().nextInt(10000)
      SagaLifecycle.associateWith("paymentId", paymentId)
      eventGateway.publish(PaymentEvent(paymentId, orderCreatedEvent.orderId))
   }
   ...
}
```

When I dispatch `OrderCreateEvent`, `ConversionException` occurs in `TokenEventProcessor#processingLoop()` as below.
[image]

application.yml is as below.

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: order-service
  datasource:
    url: mysql
    username: mysql
    password:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

axon:
  serializer:
    general: xstream
  axonserver:
    servers: localhost:8124
```

bulid.gradle

```
implementation("org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.5")
```

**Why does 'ConversionException' occur in 'TrackingEventProcessor' of Axon framework?**

Comment: I found a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126219/axon-complaining-on-com-thoughtworks-xstream-converters-conversionexception-fai

Comment: The `ConversionException` you receive occurs from within the `XStreamSerializer` used by Axon Framework to serialize the `TrackingToken` and store it in your `TokenStore`. Why it is failing is, however, not clear. Would you be able to update your issue by adding the entire stack trace of the exception?

Additionally, the "solution" you have shared is not really solving the conversion issue. It is just a workaround, changing the serializer used by the framework from XStream to Jackson.